# How can manage layout screen for all android phone?

Tags: android

I have two cell phones.When I run same app on both phone is not properly work. For fix that problem i use sw120dip and sw360dip layout. But i cant solve this error.
How can i solve this error.

Comment: Please provide a bit more information so we can help you. Perhaps the layouts you're currently using, as well as some screen shots to demonstrate what's not properly working.

Comment: Try to post Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example.

Comment: Google "Supporting Multiple Screen Sizes Android".  It's the top search result.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Relative layout` by the way if you are using other layout and design it with the Android Studio Design instead of using xml .In this way you can see the layout of screen without running the app on real phone.

Answer (score 0):

If you use relative layout with all dimensions in "dp" and font sizes in "sp" then it has to fit in all screen size. I have never seen scenario unless one is using fixed layout. Pls paste your layout to get more details about your questions.